# LWC: How to get access to proper Error message when statically calling an Apex method from LWC?

Tags: error-messages, lightning-web-components

I call an Apex method statically.

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Id insertx(){
insert new Account();
}
```

From a LWC component:

```
insertx().then( () => {})
.catch(error => {this.error = error;})
```

My problem is that the message returned is:
"An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 830852859-43925 (1007478720)"

Anyone knows how to get a proper message from Apex?
I also tried using a try/catch and throwing an AuraException but it gave the same result

```
try{
// a required field is missing
insert new Account();
}
        catch(Exception e){
            Database.rollback(sp);
            System.debug(Logginglevel.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            throw new AuraException(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting a `System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 1` when trying to insert the record?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira I can see its not cacheable, the exception would likely be required field missing

Comment: I asked because that's the error I got when trying the exact same logic of inserting an empty account. The error handled by the component is the "internal server error" message, although the Apex code fails because apparently DML operations are not allowed (like if there was a `readOnly` attribute in a Visualforce page). The method I tried doesn't use `cacheable=true`, but even if I do use it, the result is the same.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal See this code: https://gist.github.com/renatoliveira/885caaf032740881af0ed922eb408623.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to throw `AuraException`, instead, you have to throw

[AuraHandledException (for Aura components only)](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html)

[AuraHandledException (for LWC components)](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/08/error-handling-best-practices-for-lightning-web-components)

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static string insertAccount(){
        try{
        // a required field is missing
        insert new Account();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
           
            System.debug(Logginglevel.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

In Console:

`{"ok":false,"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request","body":{"message":"Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Account Name]: [Account Name]"}}`

Throwing any exception other than `AuraHandledException` gives internal server error.

Comment: So the thing is to return a String on the controller method instead of an unsupported type, like Id? Because that’s the only difference I can see between your code and the one on that gist.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira check my comments on your gist

Comment: Just did. Thanks for the clarification!